# How do I disable/remove the Palette of an Eclipse Graphiti editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, graphiti

Trying to remove the palette of a Eclipse Graphiti editor.

`org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DiagramBehavior` has a `createPaletteBehaviour()` to override but if I return `null`, the editor crashes.

I also tried this in the diagram behavior, but I actually don't want it collapsed but removed:

```
@Override
protected DefaultPaletteBehavior createPaletteBehaviour() {
    return new DefaultPaletteBehavior(this) {
        @Override
        public FlyoutPreferences getPalettePreferences() {
            FlyoutPreferences palettePreferences = super.getPalettePreferences();
            palettePreferences.setPaletteState(FlyoutPaletteComposite.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            return palettePreferences;
        }
    };
}
```

I would also prefer to use some API instead of manipulating the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a reply in the eclipse forum:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1698886/

"**you can override isShowFlyoutPalette()** in your tool behavior provider and 
return false there to hide the palette."

This is what I was looking for.

Comment: FYI: As far as I know, Graphiti internally also uses the hack described in your previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30908505/), as GEF does not provide an API method to hide the FlyoutPalette. (This is just meant as background info)

Answer (score 0):

This is the hack I came up with, there is a `org.eclipse.gef.ui.palette.FlyoutPaletteComposite.STATE_HIDDEN` with the value "8", since the constant is private (and probably should not be used) I have to set it directly.

```
@Override
protected DefaultPaletteBehavior createPaletteBehaviour() {
    return new DefaultPaletteBehavior(this) {
        @Override
        public FlyoutPreferences getPalettePreferences() {
            FlyoutPreferences palettePreferences = super.getPalettePreferences();
            palettePreferences.setPaletteState(8);
            return palettePreferences;
        }
    };
}
```

But as mentioned I would prefer API instead of this preferences hack.